# Citus Row Based Distribution

Tags: citus

Does the Citus Row-Based sharding needs to make sure that all tables in the schema have the distribution column and that all queries in the application filter by it?

Does it mean all tables in Data based sharding need to have Distribution Key column included?
Any other mandatory requirement for Row-Based sharding?

all tables in Data based sharding need not have Distribution Key column included as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the tables must have a distribution column. A database, or a schema, might have both distributed and local tables at the same time. That means you can choose which tables to be distributed.

Distributed tables should have a distribution column, unless it is a reference table. Please take a look into Citus docs for details.

https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v11.2/get_started/concepts.html